# "Error: no matching function for call..." in declaring pair

Tags: c++

I'm declaring type `movement` as a pair of pair of `int`s, but the `Piece.cpp` initialization returns the following error. Why?

```
Piece.cpp:54:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<std::pair<int, int>,
  std::pair<int, int> >::pair(int&, int&)’
```

**Globals.hpp**

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_HPP_
#define GLOBALS_HPP_
typedef std::pair< std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> > movement;
#endif /* GLOBALS_HPP_ */
```

**Piece.cpp**

```
#include "Globals.hpp"
#include "Piece.hpp"
using namespace std;

vector<movement> generatePossibleMovements() {
    vector<movement> pm;
    int i, j, m, n;
    movement m((i,j), (m,n));
    pm.push_back(m);
    return pm;
}
```

Comment: You need to include `<utility>`, and `<vector>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
movement mo((i,j), (m,n));
```

In this declaration, `(i,j)` and `(m,n)` are uses of the comma operator. They will evaluate to the values of `j` and `n` respectively. So your declaration is the same as:

```
movement mo(j, n);
```

This trying to construct a `std::pair` of `std::pair`s using only two `int`s.

One way to construct the inner pairs explicitly is to do:

```
movement mo(std::make_pair(i,j), std::make_pair(m,n));
```

Perhaps a nicer syntax closer to what you were trying is:

```
movement mo({i, j}, {m, n});
```

This will initialise the arguments to the constructor with `{i, j}` and `{m, n}` respectively. If you prefer your initialisations to be consistent, you can do:

```
movement mo{{i, j}, {m, n}};
// or
movement mo = {{i, j}, {m, n}};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to `#include <utility>`.

You also have a typo; you're trying to create two locals named `m`:

```
int i, j, m, n;
//        ^
movement m((i,j), (m,n));
//       ^
```

Finally, the real problem here is how you're trying to construct the `pair`.  You're assuming that the inner `pair`s will be constructed even though you haven't actually said you want to construct a pair:

```
movement x((i,j), (m,n));
```

It's probably best to just use `make_pair` instead:

```
movement x(make_pair (i,j), make_pair (m,n));
```